# Run Two Commands on CLI

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku, command-line-interface

I'm trying to run the following code on my CLI:

```
$ rails new sample_app --skip-test-unit & --database=postgresql
[1] 3452
sh.exe": --database=postgresql:command not found
```

The only part of the command that runs is the the first part (--skip-test-unit).

If you have guidance on what might be wrong or how I might troubleshoot further I'd appreciate it. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no need for the `&`:

```
 rails new sample_app --skip-test-unit --database=postgresql
```

Works :)

Comment: Thanks!! Sorry for the ridiculous question,  I've just started learning rails

Comment: @user2980537 No problem at all, that was a good question, I had way worse questions starting off.. If you've anymore, feel free to ask away, or chat to me, we're all here to help :)

Comment: I'm glad you're able to help because in reality I do have another problem with my Rails application, but to be brutally honest I do not how to chat with users (also new to stackoverflow). Anyway you could help?

Comment: @LeoCosta not even 100% myself, the only way I know is after a couple of comments it suggests it, how about you email npaterson1[at]gmail[dot].com and I'll get back to you there?